# How do I select the 2nd a attribute in a list with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Okay, this has been bugging me for a bit -- How do you actually select the 2nd **a** attribute in a list like this?

```
<li class="coolstuff">
    <a href="">CoolStuff1</a>
</li>
<li class="coolstuff">
    <a href="">CoolStuff2</a>
</li>
```

I'm looking at `.coolstuff > a:nth-child(2)` but it isn't working...

Comment: well thanks for the answers, and the lovely downvote -- it didn't occur to me the nth-child selector could be used this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS should be:

```
li.coolstuff:nth-child(2) a
```

Comment: I've made an edit. i didn't see it was the class inside the `li`

Comment: for anyone else referencing this, it can also be done without the li at the front -- meaning .coolstuff:nth-child(2) a works the same as li.coolstuff:nth-child(2)

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
.coolstuff:nth-child(2) a
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rjmrd/)**

Comment: funny. I tried that and it didn't work. i'm going to have to review the html part...

Comment: ah I think I know why. I put it after a instead of before... well, crap.

Answer (score 1):

The usuage is

```
.coolstuff:nth-child(2) a
```

**JSFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/neekdamon/G7arK/1/

Comment: Why are you answering in jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 I totally overlooked it! Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right.
Instead of

```
.coolstuff > a:nth-child(2)
```

The way to address it correctly is:

```
.coolstuff:nth-child(2) a
```

Because you want to get the second .coolstuff and it's a. ([JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2Tv8/))

Not every coolstuff's second a! ([Your current code example - JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKwgQ/))